# Upgrading 5.6 to 8.0 without losing any data

Tags: mysql

I am using windows server. As per need of project I need to upgrade MySQL from 5.6 to 8.0 but I already have the existing databases and tables. How should I upgrade without losing any data in windows?

Comment: how did you do that? without loosing your data?

Answer (score 1):

backup your data to sql dump file and upgrade by incrementing major version. 5.6 to 6 to 7 to 8.

Comment: Good luck finding a version 6 and 7.

Comment: The sequence is:  5.6 - 5.7 - 8.0

Answer (score 1):

Backup the database

```
mysqldump -u *username* -p *databasename* > *location\backup*.sql
```

If you have stored procedures and triggers, use

```
mysqldump -u *username* -p --routines --triggers *databasename* > *location\backup*.sql
```

After backing up, test the restoration in a test machine having mysql8 installed, and confirm there are no unexpected errors

```
mysql -u *username* -p *databasename* < *location\backup*.sql
```

Then proceed with the restoration in the server.

There will be downtime during upgradation and the time will be depending on your database size